# 422 Error: (Unprocessable Entity)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ionic-framework

I am new, so I apologize in advance if there is some issues with my explanation of my issue, I am using Ionic v1. on the frontend and this ruby tutorial for the backend: https://www.simplify.ba/articles/2016/06/18/creating-rails5-api-only-application-following-jsonapi-specification/.

I am trying to create a user and have that information stored in the backend, but continue to run into a 422 (Unprocessable Entity Error). I have read many different forums, but am stuck.

Here's my front end:

```
.controller('SignupCtrl', function($scope,SignupSession,$ionicPopup) {

  $scope.signup = function(full_name, password, repeat_password) {
    var user_session = new SignupSession({ user: { full_name: full_name, password: password }});
    user_session.$save(
      function(data){
        window.localStorage['full_name'] = full_name;
        window.localStorage['password'] = password;
        $location.path('/app/playlists');
      },
      function(err){
        $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: 'An error occured',
          template: err["data"]["error"]
        });
      }
    );
  }
})

.factory('SignupSession', function($resource) {
   return $resource(window.server_url + "/users.json") //application/vnd.api+json
  })
```

Here's my backend:

User Controller:

```
def create
  user = User.new(user_params)
  if user.save
    render json: user, status: :created, meta: default_meta
  else
    render_error(user, :unprocessable_entity)
  end
end

def user_params
  ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse(params)
end
```

Sessions Controller:

```
def create
  data = ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse(params)
  Rails.logger.error params.to_yaml
  user = User.where(full_name: data[:full_name]).first
  head 406 and return unless user
  if user.authenticate(data[:password])
    user.regenerate_token
    render json: user, status: :created, meta: default_meta,
           serializer: ActiveModel::Serializer::SessionSerializer and return
  end
```

Here's my log and info from Google Chrome:

```
Started POST "/users.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-04 12:40:39 -0700
Processing by UsersController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"full_name"=>"btejes@yahoo.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[36mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[31mrollback transaction[0m
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::ErrorSerializer with ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::JsonApi (0.29ms)
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 6ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

{errors: [{source: {pointer: "/data/attributes/password"}, detail: "can't be blank"},…]}
errors
:
[{source: {pointer: "/data/attributes/password"}, detail: "can't be blank"},…]
```

Does it have something to do with the content type needing to have, "application/vnd.api+json" in the front end? Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I apologize in advance that this post is on the longer side.

Ben

Comment: For some reason the password is blank, check the params by debugging the method when you make the request.

Comment: Thanks, Sepastian! It's odd because I check the logs and it shows that user and password is being passed there though. I did find that when I expanded and the error below seem to think user name is also blank: 
{source: {pointer: "/data/attributes/full-name"}, detail: "can't be blank"}
detail
:
"can't be blank"
source
:
{pointer: "/data/attributes/full-name"}
pointer
:
"/data/attributes/full-name"

Comment: I recommend you to check the params that come to your method, maybe it says the password is blank because the request is sending just '', and not the password being passed, use `byebug` right after your method and see the params in the rails server